# Compare Online Webpage to Offline Webpage Software

Tags: html, comparison

I need to find some software that will compare a public-facing webpage to a non-public-facing webpage of the same page.

Basically, the public webpage is live and the non-public page is about to go live, but I need to check it matches the current one first.

I have had a look at `wraith` and `happo` but have had no luck with either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way around this was to use `wraith`.

```
> wraith capture capture.yaml
```

This has worked too when I use the `spider.yaml` file too.

```
> wraith spider spider.yaml
```

Spider would crawl the website to get the links, then by adding them to the `capture.yaml` file would then let the capture take the screenshots of the webpage.